# How to onClick listener on DropdownMenuItem

Tags: flutter

I have build the code of DropdownMenuItem, now when i click an item from dropdownmenuitem it should move to another screen.Below is the code

```
class TimesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TimesScreenState createState() => _TimesScreenState();
}

class _TimesScreenState extends State<TimesScreen> {
  var gender;
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
DropdownButton(
                     hint: Text("Select",
                     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                     onChanged: (val){
                         setState(() {
                           this.gender=val;
                         });
                     },
                     value: this.gender,
                     items: [
                       DropdownMenuItem(
                         //onTap:
                         value: 'Earth',
                         child: Text('Earth'
                        ),
                       ),
                       DropdownMenuItem(
                        //onTap:
                         value: 'Mars',
                         child: Text('Mars'
                        ),
                       ),)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your `Text` widget with `GestureDetector` to which has an `onTap` function which you can use to execute your desired code. For more details look at this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html

This should work:

```
DropdownMenuItem(
    value: 'Earth',
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        // navigate code...
      },
      child: Text('Earth')
    ),
),
```

Answer (score -1):

After applying fayeed's solution, I noticed that this only makes the *text* inside the dropdown clickable. To fix this, you can simply use `DropdownButton.onChanged`.

Full widget:

```dart
class TimesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TimesScreenState createState() => _TimesScreenState();
}

class _TimesScreenState extends State<TimesScreen> {
  var gender;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton(
      hint: Text("Select"),
      value: this.gender,
      items: [
        DropdownMenuItem(value: 'Earth', child: Text('Earth')),
        DropdownMenuItem(value: 'Mars', child: Text('Mars')),
      ],
      onChanged: (val) {
        setState(() {
          this.gender = val;
        });
        switch (val) {
          case 'Earth':
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/earth_target_page');
            break;
          case 'Mars':
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/mars_target_page');
            break;
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```